# preventDefault() not working in Mobile but works fine on computer

Tags: javascript

```
mobVerificationView.validateNumerals = function(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 58) && charCode != 8 && charCode != 9)
{ 
    evt.preventDefault();
}
return ;
}
```

This works just fine on any browser on the computer, but this doesn't work on mobile. 
The function is getting called on the key press , and I have verified the charCode to be accurate. I added breakpoints and the preventDefault() is called and executed as well however the character are still being printed.
I have used a onkeydown in the HTML tag:

```
<input type="text"  tabindex="-1" 
maxlength="10" placeholder="New Mobile Number" class="txt_otp 
update_input" id="txt_newmobile" 
onkeydown="javascript:mobVerificationView.validateNumerals(event)"/>
```

Comment: Try the `input` event instead. I believe some softkeyboards don't trigger keydown

Comment: Can you please see the console of charcode first.

Comment: @UllasHunka I think only onkeypress generates charCode, which is depricated.

Comment: Have you tried stop propagation

Comment: @UllasHunka I haven't tried to stop propagation, but I don't think that would do anything, still i'll try it anyway and  see what happens

Comment: @bambam but the function validateNumericals is getting called. I need to check what type of keyCode do these softkeyboard output.